# How to list external R code without executing it in Knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I have an R file with several helper functions which I want to append to my Knitr document. How do I import this file into knitr without evaluating it and at the same time listing it in the document ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `\`\`\`{r eval=FALSE}\`\`\``

Comment: I think it's as easy as setting `eval = FALSE` for a code chunk.  Edited to say that @Andrie beat me to it by 8 seconds.

Comment: And I used fancy backticks.  :-)